# Perplexed by simple XPath bug

Tags: php, html, dom, xpath

```
<?php
$response = 
'<style><div id="subhead"></div></style>';
//echo $response;

$doc = new DOMDocument();

$doc->loadHTML($response);  

$finder = new DomXPath($doc);

$term_select = $finder->query('//div[@id="subhead"]');

var_dump($term_select->item(0));

?>
```

The var_dump gets NULL, and I also get this Warning on line 8:

```
Warning: DOMDocument::loadHTML(): Unexpected end tag : div in Entity, line: 1 on line 8
```

Note that this is not my HTML (I'm scraping), so changing the HTML is not an option.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that you can't have a DIV element instead a STYLE one so when you use `loadHTML`, it fails to validate the HTML. If you did a `$doc->saveHTML();` you would have quickly realized that it's wrapping the `<div id="subhead">` in `CDATA`.

To solve the problem, use `loadXML()` instead.

```
$doc->loadXml($response);
```

Comment: Thanks again!  Turns out I have another problem but I'll post as a new question if I can't solve it..

Comment: Posted the new problem with loadXML here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6393401/problem-with-invalid-xml-html-in-php-dom

Comment: @babonk - I provided an answer to your new question.

Answer (score 2):

`loadHTML()` expects to find HTML in the string, but that is not valid HTML, so the string does not get loaded properly. XPath will not have that `<div>` element to get to. Try `loadXML()` instead.