# Problem with invalid XML/HTML in PHP DOM

Tags: php, html, xml, dom

Suppose you have the following HTML:

```
<style><input><div name="myDiv"></div></style>
```

You want to load it into a PHP DOMDocument object, how should you do it?  If you use `$doc->loadHTML()` it will have the problem that the `<div>` is inside the `<style>` tag.  If you use `$doc->loadXML()` it will have the problem that the `<input>` tag doesn't close.

Note: I can't edit the HTML, only the PHP used to parse it, because I'm scraping here.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try this:

```
$doc = new DOMDocument;
$doc->recover = true;
$doc->loadXml($response);
```

The `$doc->recover = true` tells DOMDocument to try and parse non-well formed documents. See the [documentation](http://www.php.net/manual/en/class.domdocument.php#domdocument.props.recover) for more information.

Answer (score 0):

Can't you turn the html into a string, explode it and then stitch it back with the closing tag?

Comment: This is just a small segment of the HTML i'm dealing with.  there are tons of inputs and tons of invalid tags (like divs inside styles).  This is just a small sample to show the problem